# How to call a modal window in kendo grid column template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

currently I am working to display a modal window once you click on a link in Kendo Grid. Below is my code:

```
{
    field:"filename",
    title: "File Name",
    width: 60,
    template: '<a href='javascript:(function() {$("win").kendoWindow();})();'><span id="win">#:filename#</span></a>'
},
```

What is happening now is that, the file, which is a json, is just displayed as its file name, but what I need to show is the content inside the file. Is there any way that this could be done? Would appreciate any help given.

I have tried `<a target="_blank"></a>` which opens in a new tab, but I need it to open in a new modal window instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is invalid. You can't add a pure javascript code to a string. It is not the way it works. You are probably getting errors in your console. Also, you have some other flaws in your code:

- You should not add more than one element with the same id in your dom like you're doing with `<span id='win'></span>`. Change it a class instead.
- If you open a window in that span, it will break the column's content. [Check this](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJaDa).

What I would suggest is this code:

Template:

```
template: '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open-modal">#:filename#</a>'
```

Click event:

```
$("#grid").on("click", "a.open-modal", function() {
    $("<div></div>").appendTo($("#win")).kendoWindow();
});
```

Where `#win` is a `div` element in your body.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJaDa/2)

In the click event - which is attached to the grid and filtered by the link's class `.open-modal` - it just creates a new `div`, appends it to `div#win` and then call `kendoWindow` on it.

**Update**

- To get window centered when showing, just use [`center()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-center) method;
- To get the data of the clicked row, get the `tr` from the clicked link, then use [`dataItem()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem) method from grid with it.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJaDa/5)

Comment: I have done the above, as you stated. Good news is that is a modal window being opened. However, there is nothing displayed inside the modal window and how do I set the modal window to appear based on the link i have clicked. Currently by default, all modal windows are opening at the same position which is at the bottom of the grid, as per your demo link.

Comment: @MitchellY I didn't said anything about the window because it wasn't specified in the question. Anyway, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Now there is at least something going on there. Doing this, however, affects my grid when it loads. Nothing is displayed on initial load, but when you click 'next page', data is populated back again. 

And I'm still figuring out how to load the contents of the file when the modal window is open. Do you have any idea how that is done. Truly appreciate your response.

Comment: @MitchellY I'm glad to help. But I'm afraid your question is getting out of the scope here. To get help on another problem, I suggest you to create another question with proper information about it. If this question is solved, mark it as answered and go for a new one.

Comment: My apologies. I have created a new qn,

Comment: @MitchellY no problem. Send me the link, then I see if I can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134076/discussion-between-mitchell-y-and-dontvotemedown).